# Isn't it using the wrong angle?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is an example in the book, Linear Algebra Done Wrong

Example. Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the reflection in the line $x_1 = 3x_2$. The author provided a method with 3 steps. Let $\gamma$ be the angle between the $x_1$ axis and the line $x_1 = 3x_2$, and first rotate the plane by the angle $-\gamma$ in order to move the line to the $x_1$ axis, and using the rotation matrix below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Fwc.png)

Then multiplied with a reflection matrix ($T_0$, special for $x_1$ axis) and then rotate back by $\gamma$. Thus we get this

$$T = (R_\gamma)T_0(R_{-\gamma})$$

My question is, it is OK to rotate the plane by $-\gamma$ to move the line to the $x_1$ axis. However, I think the first angle should be $\gamma$ but not $-\gamma$ since the rotation matrix rotates the points on the plane but not the plane itself. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format, for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you are wrong.

You might want to try it with, say the line $x_1 = x_2$.. Then the angle is $45$ degrees, and so the rotation matrix $R_\gamma$ is just
$$
R_\gamma = \pmatrix{s &-s \\
s & s},
$$
where $s = \frac{\sqrt{2}}2$, and $R_{-\gamma}$ is just the transpose of that. Now try multiplying out the three matrices both ways, and see which one ends up flipping about the line $x = y$. It'll be easy to test: apply it to the vector $\pmatrix{1\\1}$; if it's the right transformation, this vector will remain fixed.

By "apply", I mean "put that vector to the right of the product of the three matrices, and do the multiplication."

Comment: You are right, professor. Here are some questions.

Comment: Would you please show me how to construct the cartesian coordinate system? I mean, which one should be the vertical axis and which should be horizontal with the line x1 = x2?

Comment: Another question is, where would the line x1 = x2 be after the first rotation? Apologize for my request but I am just a new guy in la.